# How do I put extra-statements in list-initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given I have a class with a constructor which looks as follows:

```
MClass(const char *t_source);
```

In fact there are a lot of places where `t_source` is obtained from a file, so I'm considering making another constructor which takes `FILE` pointer instead and put most of the boilerplate inside of it. At the same time existing constructor also has a lot of use by itself and contains logic which i don't want to repeat more than once in the code. I was thinking about delegating constructor but can't see any way how i can leverage this feature as i need more than one statement to extract data from a `FILE` instance (like allocating a char array and reading from the `FILE` and deleting afterward). So essentially I want to do something like this:

```
MClass(FILE *t_file) : MClass(MNameSpace::readFile(t_file)) {}
```

But with some preliminary and post-call actions. Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you put the common code into a (posibly static) method of the class and call it from both constructors?

Comment: Please show a [mre] of an implementation with two separate constructors in which you DO copy the same code. That would allow answering by modifying that code to still act the same but not have copied code.

Comment: delegate constructors. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352020/member-initializer-list-initialize-two-members-from-a-function-returning-a-tupl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find your case to be better solved by the named constructor idiom. Rather than trying to pigeonhole complexity into the limited space provided by the constructor context, I would simply add a new named function.

```
class MClass {
  // ...
public:
  static MClass fromFile(FILE *t_file);
};

MClass MClass::fromFile(FILE *t_file) {
  // Preparation
  MClass retVal(...);
  // Post actions
  return retVal;
}
```

Simple, easy to understand, and does what you want. It also conveys meaning very well when one sees

```
MClass obj = MClass::fromFile(...);
```

To boot, the named return value optimization (standardized) will avoid any extra copies from using a named function. The net result will be a single constructor invocation to initialize `obj` directly.

Comment: Aaaand .... there (in the edit) is the `static` I was waiting for...